# Passing NSDate to a local UIWebView in iOS - Objective C

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, uiwebview, nsdate

I have a app with a menu that loads various UIWebViews that load from local HTML Files. **(This Code is in the WebViewController)**

```
//Code for the WebView
vesperswebview.scrollView.bounces = NO;
[[vesperswebview scrollView] setBounces:NO];
[(UIScrollView*)[vesperswebview.subviews objectAtIndex:0] setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:NO];

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:@"data/html"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSString *theAbsoluteURLString = [url absoluteString];
NSString *queryString = @"#?manifest=Psalmody-Morning";
NSString *absoluteURLwithQueryString = [theAbsoluteURLString stringByAppendingString:queryString];
NSURL *finalURL = [NSURL URLWithString:absoluteURLwithQueryString];

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:finalURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:(NSTimeInterval)10.0];
[vesperswebview loadRequest:request];
```

I also have a custom date picker called FlatDate Picker: **(This code is in my main ViewController), It is linked to a imported FlatDatePicker open source project I got from GitHub.**

```
- (void)flatDatePicker:(FlatDatePicker*)datePicker dateDidChange:(NSDate*)date {
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    NSCalendar *coptic = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:@"coptic"];
    [dateFormatter setCalendar:coptic];
    [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];

    if (datePicker.datePickerMode == FlatDatePickerModeDate) {
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE, MMMM, dd, yyyy"];
    } else if (datePicker.datePickerMode == FlatDatePickerModeDate) {
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
    } else {
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE, MMMM, dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
    }
    NSString *value = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
    self.labelDateSelected.text = value;
}
```

My Question is, When I select the date in my main view controller, how can that date be saved and passed on to the next view to load the appropriate Javascript that is **date sensitive** in my database?

Comment: There are so many ways to achieve this. 1) Define a variable dateString in the WebViewController and set it when the user selects the date and push the WebViewController. 2) If you are always showing both the ViewControllers, then use the delegate pattern to update the WebViewController once the user taps on DatePicker. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/DelegatesandDataSources/DelegatesandDataSources.html.

Comment: I have read through the documentation you linked multiple times and I have had this problem for months now, would you mind providing code in a direct answer please? You would make my life lol

Comment: Then I need more info on whats your implementation is. Like I said I have few assumptions how are you showing your WebViewController, Do you allow users to pick the date first. Then you push the WebViewController and display the HTML.

Comment: That is exactly how it works

Comment: Actually you are storing the `NSDate` text value in the `self.labelDateSelected.text`. Create a `NSDate` variable in `WebViewController` lets say `NSDate *jsDate`. Assign this value just before you push or present the `WebViewController`. Create date from `self.labelDateSelected.text`. In the `viewDidLoad` of `WebViewController` fetch the javascript from database using the query with value of `jsDate`.

Comment: Do you mind writing out how you would do this in a complete answer? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Share the project (demo is also fine) will edit and send it to you.

Comment: What is your email?

Comment: vasa.sac@gmail.com

Comment: I sent you an email earlier today:))

Comment: @MinaDawoud, is this issue resolved?

Comment: no it is not @KrishnaChaitanyaAmjuri

Comment: can you please tell me which JavaScript Date Format are you using? `ISO Date`, `Short Date`, `Long Date`, `Full Date`.

Comment: i can email you the project @KrishnaChaitanyaAmjuri

Comment: sure, chait.amjuri@gmail.com

Comment: @KrishnaChaitanyaAmjuri Sent!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127448/discussion-between-krishna-chaitanya-amjuri-and-mina-dawoud).

Comment: Perfect, do you have a solution?

Comment: Hi, please check my answer. I went through your code. I had some doubts. You didn't have a method when I click the select button. So, I didn't know which `ViewController` you were loading. I believe you have an idea about this. So, feel free to comment if you need any clarity in implementing this.

Comment: May I know whether the answer I gave is working or not?

Comment: Hi, I would like to know whether you got your issue resolved or not

Answer (score 1):

Given how the FlatDatePicker looks, the date obtained from it can be converted to the following JavaScript DateFormats

> ISO Date "2015-03-25" (The International Standard)
>
> Short Date "03/25/2015" or "2015/03/25"
>
> Long Date "Mar 25 2015" or "25 Mar 2015"

To convert `NSDate` into those formats. The following can be done

```
NSDateFormatter *ISODateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[ISODateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-mm-dd"];
    
NSDateFormatter *ShortDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[ShortDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy/mm/dd"];
    
NSDateFormatter *LongDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[LongDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd MMM yyyy"];
    
NSString *ISODate = [ISODateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
NSString *ShortDate = [ShortDateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
NSString *LongDate = [LongDateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
```

You can save this date in `selectedDate` variable. Then, you can have an init property in `UIViewController` like this

```
@interface JSViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *currentDate;

@end

-(instancetype)initWithDate:(NSString *)jsDate {
     self = [super initWithNibName:NULL bundle:NULL];
     if (self) {
       _currentDate = jsDate;
     }
     return self;
 }
```

You can initialize and launch this `ViewController` from the other one in the following way.

```
JSViewController *jsVC = [[JSViewController alloc] initWithDate:ISODate];
[self presentViewController:jsVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Try this once. Feel free to ping me if it doesn't work. Feel free to suggest edits to make it better.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiwebview/1617963-stringbyevaluatingjavascriptfrom?language=objc) (when using `UIWebView`) or [`evaluateJavaScript:completionHandler:`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/webkit/wkwebview/1415017-evaluatejavascript?language=objc) (when using `WKWebView`) to call a JavaScript function that will set the date of your loaded html.

If you use Segues to present the `WebViewController` from your `ViewController` you can use `prepareForSegue` to hand the date from one to the other:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue: (UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender: (id)sender {
    // Make sure your segue name in storyboard is the same as this line
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString: @"SEGUE_NAME"]) {
        // Get reference to the WebViewController
        WebViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];

        // Pass the date to the WebViewController
        [vc setSelectedDate: mySuperAwesomeDate];
    }
}
```